# Workflow Conditional Statement Not Working

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a very simple (yet redundant) workflow that isn't running correctly.

The workflow consists of multiple if/else statements.  The two conditional fields (Cost Impact and Schedule Impact) are both numeric ranging from 1-5.  The first step in the image below is so that I could verify there were indeed values.

[image: im1]

Here is the section of the if statement that the workflow should step into (see image below for proof of values).

[image]

Here are the results.  As you can see, both of my conditional fields = 5 in this particular scenario, yet the if/else statement isn't picking it up.  What am I doing wrong here?

[image: img2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a local variable as string type, then set the variable with the field value , in your case (Cost Impact), use the variable in your if statement  instead of using your field.

and do the same in the other field as well.

[image]

[image]